# Dyamic Grouping by lodash

Tags: javascript, tree, group-by, lodash

Currently doing a tree with flat data structure using lodash. but manually passing the property to generate the group. i want to separate the tree creation function with two parameters

```
function makeTree(data,properties){}
```

Current data structure

```js
var data =  [
  {"taskID": 1,"taskTitle": "Project Meeting","tagID": 23,"tagName": "IT Project V4","tagTypeID": 2,"tagType": "Project"},
  {"taskID": 1,"taskTitle": "Project Meeting","tagID": 5,"tagName": "Customer 1","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"},
  {"taskID": 1,"taskTitle": "Project Meeting","tagID": 19,"tagName": "Project 3","tagTypeID": 2,"tagType": "Project"},
  {"taskID": 1,"taskTitle": "Project Meeting","tagID": 14,"tagName": "Internal Dev","tagTypeID": 3,"tagType": "Development"},
  {"taskID": 1,"taskTitle": "Project Meeting","tagID": 4,"tagName": "Customer 2","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"},
  {"taskID": 2,"taskTitle": "Weekly Team Meeting","tagID": 10,"tagName": "IT Project","tagTypeID": 2,"tagType": "Project"},
  {"taskID": 2,"taskTitle": "Weekly Team Meeting","tagID": 11,"tagName": "Project 2","tagTypeID": 2,"tagType": "Project"},
  {"taskID": 2,"taskTitle": "Weekly Team Meeting","tagID": 14,"tagName": "Internal Dev","tagTypeID": 3,"tagType": "Development"},
  {"taskID": 2,"taskTitle": "Weekly Team Meeting","tagID": 23,"tagName": "IT Project V4","tagTypeID": 2,"tagType": "Project"},
  {"taskID": 3,"taskTitle": "Release Planing","tagID": 10,"tagName": "IT Project","tagTypeID": 2,"tagType": "Project"},
  {"taskID": 3,"taskTitle": "Release Planing","tagID": 7,"tagName": "Inpex","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"},
  {"taskID": 3,"taskTitle": "Release Planing","tagID": 2,"tagName": "Agrium","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"},
  {"taskID": 3,"taskTitle": "Release Planing","tagID": 3,"tagName": "Sain Gobain","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"},
  {"taskID": 3,"taskTitle": "Release Planing","tagID": 4,"tagName": "Customer 2","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"},
  {"taskID": 3,"taskTitle": "Release Planing","tagID": 5,"tagName": "Customer 1","tagTypeID": 1,"tagType": "Customer"}

];



 var output= _(data).groupBy('tagType').map(function (value, key) {
            return {
                value: key,
                children : _(value).groupBy('tagName').map(function(val,key){
    return { value : key, children : _(val).groupBy('taskTitle').map(function(v,k){ return { value : v,children:[]}}).value() }
   }).value()
            }
        }).value();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this recursive solution.
The benefit is that it's going to work with any number of properties to group.

```js
let makeTree = function (data, properties) {
 let curPropName = properties[0];
 let remainingProps = _.drop(properties, 1);

 return _(data)
  .groupBy(curPropName)
  .map(function (val, key) {
   if (properties.length > 1) {
    return {
     value: key,
     children: makeTree(val, remainingProps)
    };
   } else {
    return {value: val, children: []};
   }
  })
  .value();
};

//To get the same result as you get now call it like this
let tree = makeTree(data, ['tagType', 'tagName', 'taskTitle']);
```